# JList - `setListData()` causes `getSelectedValue()` to return null

Tags: java, arrays, jlist

When I create my JList I am able to use getSelectedValue() to print out the string I have selected in the list. As soon as I change what is inside the list everything that is returned is null.

When the list is created I have this:

```
matchList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
    String[] playerList = {"test"};
    public int getSize() { return playerList.length; }
    public String getElementAt(int i) { return playerList[i]; }
});
```

Later I change the JList to contain an array of strings:

```
matchList.setListData(Bracket.wr1);
```

Everything inside the array displays in the JList but if I try to use getSelectedValue() to get the String being displayed it just returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hm so the only problem is that there is no selected item after changing the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no selection anymore. According to the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--) `getSelectedValue()`

> [r]eturns null if there is no selection.

So if there is no default selection anymore, you should probably just set the first element as the default:

```
list.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Alright so it's no longer returning null, but now I can only have the first option on the list selected. The way the program works is that you select an item from the JList and then hit a button to enter information. I think what's happening is once the button is hit there is no longer a selection on the list. I now know that the contents of the list are not what is causing the problem.

Comment: @sumsum2 Could you please provide me with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @sumsum2 also, if the contents are not the problem it's hard for me to find out what's causing this behavior with your current code snippet

Comment: As it says on the site, I'd recommend that you create a new project and use the minimal code you think is relevant to the problem. That way, you might be even able to solve the problem yourself / describe more accurately where the problem is.